# Permission denied to read a file when running python script as service on Windows

Tags: python, winapi, windows-services

I am trying run one of the projects done in python as a windows service. It can be run as a foreground process and as a service. When we run it as a foreground process everything works fine. But when we run it as a service it gives permission denied error for one the file config file that is even used by the foreground process.
Yes I am running it as Administrator.
Here is the code for the windows service:

```
# Python script to run tevico_scanner as a windows service
# We are using pywin32 python extension modules for windows.

import servicemanager
import win32event
import win32service
import win32serviceutil

from tevico_scanner import constants
from tevico_scanner import watchman


class WindowsService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

    # Service name that we use to start/stop the service
    _svc_name_ = "<service_name>"

    # Service Display Name
    _svc_display_name_ = "<service_display_name>"

    # Description for our scanner
    _svc_service_description_ = "<description>"

    config_file = constants.DEFAULT_CFG_FILE

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.wman = watchman.Watchman(self.config_file)

        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        # Run our watchman
        watchman._CW_FLAG = False
        watchman._DEBUGGING = False
        self.wman.run()

    def SvcDoStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(WindowsService)
```

Error Message:

```
Python could not construct the class instance 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\scanner-agent-7\scripts\bin\windows_service.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.wman = watchman.Watchman(self.config_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tevico_scanner-0.6-py2.7.egg\tevico_scanner\watchman.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.config = config.Config(self.config_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tevico_scanner-0.6-py2.7.egg\tevico_scanner\config.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.load_from_file(config_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tevico_scanner-0.6-py2.7.egg\tevico_scanner\config.py", line 36, in load_from_file
    with open(config_file, 'r') as fh:
IOError: (13, 'Permission denied', 
'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\tevico_scanner\\etc\\config\\scanner.cfg') 
%2: %3
```

Thanks.

Comment: The service is running as a user that has no access to files in the Administrator account's profile directory. Comment out the problematic code, run the service, find it on the "services" tab in the task manager, click "go to details", and check the process user name.

Comment: When that line is removed the service don't even report any error. It only says that "service could not be started."